# C, issue with char* array[][]

Tags: c, arrays

I'm actually writing a script to access a database.
Everything about accessing and using mysql.h seem ok.
I store the result of a request in a char* array[ ][ ], and when i print the content of my array within the function everything is still fine. Also when i print the content from the "Main" function.
But here is my issue : i made a function to print content of arrays (to ensure myself every step of the script is ok) and when i try to print the content i got a "segmentation error". 
I understand that there is probably a problem about the function'memory access but after many tries(and hours) i still can't find out a solution, it is beyond my poor skills..

Can someone explain to me the reason of that problem and maybe suggest a solution or an alternative way to work?

here is the script :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mariadb/mysql.h>

void get_id_and_zone_of_grid_point(char* id_zone_array[2][60], MYSQL mysql) ;
void display_2D_string_array(char* array[2][100]) ;


int main()
{
  MYSQL mysql ;

  char* array_id_zone[2][60] ;

  mysql_init(&mysql) ;

  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "option");

  if (mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "127.0.0.1", "vent_monteynard_weather_forecasts_writer", "***", "vent_monteynard", 0, NULL, 0))
  {
    printf("connection successfull\n") ;

    get_id_and_zone_of_grid_point(array_id_zone, mysql) ;
    display_2D_string_array(array_id_zone) ;

    mysql_close(&mysql);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("error during connection!");
  }
  return 0;
}

/*********** Functions implementation ***********/

void get_id_and_zone_of_grid_point(char* id_zone_array[2][60], MYSQL mysql)
{
  short i = 0 ;
  short j = 0 ;

  mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT id_grib_grid_point,id_list_zone FROM grib_grid_point") ;
  MYSQL_RES *result = NULL ;
  MYSQL_ROW cell ; 
  result = mysql_store_result(&mysql) ;

  short num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result) ;
  short num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result) ;

  while ((cell = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
  {
    for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
    {
      id_zone_array[i][j] = cell[i] ? cell[i] : "NULL" ;
    }
    j++ ;
  }
  id_zone_array[0][num_rows] = "end" ;
  mysql_free_result(result);
}

void display_2D_string_array(char* array[2][100])  //issue is when i call this function
{
  int rows = 0 ;
  int fields = 0 ;

  while (strcmp(array[0][rows], "end") != 0)
  {
    for (fields = 0; fields < 2; fields++)
    {
      printf("array[%d][%d] : %s\t",fields, rows, array[fields][rows]) ;
    }
    printf("\n") ;
    rows++ ;
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot

NB : sorry if my english is not correct

Comment: I suspect freeing the result set destroys all the memory those pointers you saved off refer to. Granted, coming from an absolute MySQL nuub (me), that may be wrong, but I strongly suspect otherwise.

Comment: i though about something that way, but i can display all my array from the main

Comment: That doesn't mean a thing. If that memory really is released back to the implementation your code invokes *undefined behavior* referring to memory that is off the books. The very preamble "undefined" means it can do anything (including nothing, or even appear to work). Relying on that is a fools venture, so just don't. Make proper copies (one way or another), and manage their lifetimes elsewhere.

Comment: @Flynt Contrary to common belief, you can (often, usually) access freed data until it is overwritten or repurposed. The memory is not "going away". (That is similar to deleting a file in a file system on disk, or formatting a disk,  which does not overwrite sectors but simply re-arranges administrative information in directories and block tables.)

Comment: @WhozCraig are you suggesting not to use mysql_free_result(MYSQL_RES) ?

Comment: @Flynt Typically, you would copy the data out into structures you have control over, especially if you don't need *all* of the query result. If the latter, then i's OK to not free it, but each query needs its own result which needs to be memorized for later deletion (or you would leak).

Comment: @Peter i may understand but memory is still something opaque for me.
Ok so i should create a struct with my array in it?
something like :
struct arr
{
   char* array[ fields ][ rows ] ;
}

Comment: Right now, ` MYSQL_RES *result`  is a local variable. If you have only one query simply make it global, or pass a pointer to it into the function. If you have more than one query in a more elaborate program, you'll need an array of results (or you do whatever you want with each single one and when you are done, delete it).

Comment: it is the beginning of a bigger script with many request(include select, insert into and update).
Ok i'll do as you suggest and work with an array of result

Comment: @Flynt Never freeing the results between queries means that you are essentially reading the table contents into memory. Depending on the size of the table this may or may not be a problem. (In all reality on today's machines it's usually not, unless you have vast amounts of data and do it for several tables.)

Comment: it is gonna be a problem, i'll have, after this request, to extract some data from GRIB data (use for forecast), using the IDs i found in SQL.
problem is the function to read GRIB file load all the GRIB datas in memory (5 millions) before looking and extracting those i want.

Comment: There are two very simple rules about memory management of dynamically-allocated objects: (1) NEVER free the memory of objects in use. (2) ALWAYS free the memory of objects you don't need any more. Of course, that means you need to know which objects are in use. When trying to deduce that, please remember that `char *copy = str;` does NOT make a copy of `str`. So the memory used by `str` is still in use as long as `copy` is active.

Comment: @rici thank you for that advice, i'll engrave it in my head, i'm trying to use struct as Peter suggest before, it seems to be better.
Both of you made me understand the problem.